# How can I remove duplicate commits after changing the author on all my past commits?

Tags: git, github

I recently realized that in a Github repository that I use for work, my commits are not associated with my Github account but just show my name without any link. I figured out this is because I had my email set in git to my work email, but my Github account is associated with my personal email. I have changed my email in git, but I wanted to try to change the author on all my past commits so they'd all show as my Github account. I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-and-committer-name-email-for-multiple-commits) and I used this command from the answer since no one other than me has touched this repository:

```
git rebase -r --root --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author"
```

However when I pushed this back to Github, it now shows a duplicate of every commit dated today with my Github account as an author, while all the previous commits are still there. How can I clean up this mess? At this point I wouldn't mind just somehow removing all these duplicate commits and going back to having the commit history not be linked to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point I wouldn't mind just somehow removing all these duplicate commits and going back to having the commit history not be linked to my account.

Actually, you can have [multiple email addresses associated with your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account). Therefore I would add the additional email to your account if you want those commits linked, and reset your repo back to how it was:

```
git switch main # or whatever branch name is applicable for you
git reset --hard previous-commit-id-before-the-rebase
git push --force-with-lease
```

Note the `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`. If that errors, you'll need to fetch first and see what someone else added, and then decide how to handle it before proceeding.